# When did key locks first appear?

Tags: ancient-history

When and where did the first metal key locks appear (not the door bolts)?

When did they became widespread?

Comment: Wikipedia is your friend - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lock_%28device%29#History_of_locks

Comment: It says from the Antiquity.

Comment: And the only reference it cites is a 1957 copy of popular mechanics

Comment: Should be closed as trivial, given that WIkipedia provides an answer. That said there are two good and colorful answers below, so let's keep it open..

Answer (score 13):

During websearch, found [this material](http://samogo.net/articles.php?id=1379) (in Russian), based on the **[Ian Harrison's book "The Book of Firsts"](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Book-Firsts-Ian-Harrison/dp/1844035131)**.

According it, wooden lock was invented in the Egypt, and it looked like this:
[image]

In Rome, people started to use the metallic locks:

[image]

And in modern times English locks became popular:

- [Chubb detector lock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jeremiah_Chubb) by **Jeremiah Chubb**
- [Double–acting Lever tumbler lock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jeremiah_Chubb) by **Robert Barron**
- [Improved lock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joseph_Bramah) by **Joseph Bramah**

See also:

- [Roman door locks](http://www.historicallocks.com/en/site/hl/Other-locks/19-Keys-and-locks-from-Imperial-Rome/Roman-door-locks/)
- [Ancient Roman Key Gallery And A Brief History Lesson](http://www.nokey.com/ankeymus.html)

---

**Update, based on your comment:**

Acccording [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Papal_coat_of_arms), first keys on Papal coat of arms were in 1198, surely after the Romes invented the metallic lock. If you'll check the picture, the keys from it is in somethat similar to the Papal coat of arm's key.
[image]

Comment: In that case I wonder why on the Coat of arms of Vatican there are keys if such locks were invented only in 18th century as claimed.

Comment: @Anixx Updated the answer

Comment: To me the keys on the picture and on the coat of arms are completely different.

Comment: @Anixx But they are the same principle of use and similar form.

Comment: I do not see a similar form...

Comment: @Anixx On my second picture: 1. Long cilindric body. 2. Circle on the end of the key (in case in Vatican there a lot more fancy things, but it still similar) 3. Perpendicular main part of the key on the other end of it.

Comment: I see nothing similar, sorry...

Answer (score 4):

The [earliest known key lock](https://allmesopotamia.tumblr.com/post/14503455263/the-most-ancient-key-lock-known-is-described-by) is supposed to have been found in Nineveh, and was described by [Joseph Bonomi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joseph_Bonomi_the_Younger) in his 1857 book [Nineveh and its Palaces](https://archive.org/stream/ninevehitspalace00bono#page/170/mode/2up):

[image: Nineveh lock mechanism]

The Wikipedia article on [locks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lock_(security_device)#Antiquity) states that:

> ... Locks such as this were later developed into the Egyptian wooden pin
>   lock, which consisted of a bolt, door fixture, and key.

The "[Warded Lock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Warded_lock)" is perhaps the most recognisable form of key-lock today. These locks incorporated "wards", or fixed projections to prevent the wrong key being entered into the lock or turned. The earliest known examples of warded locks come from the Roman period. The evidence from this period seems to suggest that, although the [keys](http://romanlocks.com/Keys.htm) were made of metal (usually iron), [parts of the lock itself were still made of wood](http://www.nokey.com/ankeymus.html).

All-metal warded locks begin to appear in the late ninth century. This form of lock normally used keys that closely resemble what most people think of when they hear the word "key" today:

[image: Ancient warded lock key]

In the article [*Locksmiths Throughout History*](https://www.onlinelocksmithcourse.com/blog/locksmiths-throughout-history) they make the claim that:

> Warded locks made by English locksmiths in the years 870 – 900 AD were
>   some of the first all-metal locks ever made.

This would correspond to the Reign of [Alfred the Great](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alfred_the_Great) in Wessex. Alfred's reign was characterised by conflicts with Viking raiders and invaders. It is not hard to imagine just how useful an all-metal lock would have been when trying to defend person and property from Viking attacks! If this dating is correct, it is also easy to understand the incentives that might have led to the development of these locks in England at that time.